# Form Submit tie in with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have a button that calls a Javascript function to plot markers on a map. It checks a php file for a query to a database and plots the points that it sees. It works.

I also have a couple drop down menus that filter the query. My second button "Filter" posts the drop down data to the php file and creates the xml file that the "markers/javascript" uses to plot the points on the map. It also works.

I need 1 button to do the drop down "Post" (without navigating away from the page) and then running the Javascript function to show the markers.

Here is the site I am working on: http://socialandsober.com/meetings2.php

You can view my source code at the link. Both of these pieces work they just do not work in one click like I want them to. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use ajax which posts the form without leaving the page.  See here.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Basically you can either run the marker code and then call the ajax function, or call the marker code when you get the successful callback.  You can do ajax without jquery, I just find jquery easier.  http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/